# How to display video in html using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting video url from Json data as   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVKsd8z6scw  but how can I display this video url in iframe using jquery? it is not showing anything. if I open this youtube page and embed it then i get link as //www.youtube.com/embed/UVKsd8z6scw . How to solve this problem?

```
    //jquery
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",function(data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));

        var content='';

        $.each(data,function(index,item){
            content +='<div class="userdata">';

            content +='<div class="userurl">'+item.keywords+'</div>';
            content +='<iframe class="usevideourl" src="'+item.videourl+'"></iframe>';
            content +='<img src="'+item.thumb+'" class="userimage"></img>';
            content +='</div>';
        });
        $('#dictionary').append(content);
    });   
});
```

Comment: you need to call $('#SomeClass').append()

Comment: Yeah, how does the html you're putting into content actually get added to the DOM?

Comment: Solve what problem? You've got the embed URL from YouTube. Use that.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this you have to indeed translate your Youtube URL.
From what I understand your JSON youtube adress is "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVKsd8z6scw". 

So you have to convert it to:
"//www.youtube.com/embed/UVKsd8z6scw"

Here is a simple JS function:

```
 function transformUrl(url)
  {
       var i         = url.indexOf("=");
       var videoID   = url.substr(i+1,url.length);

      return ("//www.youtube.com/embed/"+videoID);
  }
```

so replace this:

```
content +='<iframe class="usevideourl" src="'+item.videourl+'"></iframe>';
```

by this:

```
content +='<iframe class="usevideourl" src="'+transformUrl(item.videourl)+'"></iframe>';
```

Please find below a JS fiddle using your example

[LIVE DEMO HERE : JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mjarro/5KjEW/)
http://jsfiddle.net/mjarro/5KjEW/

Answer (score -1):

You need to append your js markup to the DOM in some way.

For example:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="video"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var data = {
'keywords': 'keywords',
    'videourl': 'www.youtube.com',
    'thumb': 'mythumb.jpg'
}
var content = '';

$.each(data, function (index, item) {
    content += '<div class="userurl">' + item.keywords + '</div>';
    content += '<iframe class="usevideourl" src="' + item.videourl + '"></iframe>';
    content += '<img src="' + item.thumb + '" class="userimage"></img>';
    content += '</div>';
});

$('.video').append(content);
```

Or, you could dynamically create the container then append all within the loop.